# Why $142857$ when multiplied by $1$ to $6$ gives the same digits?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

What made 142857 a special number?
Why it gives the same digits if it is multiplied by 1,2,3,4,5 & 6 ?
And gives all nines when it is multiplied by 7?

Comment: Please include source/motivation for this question.

Comment: It just got struck in my head... And it started as a puzzle to me

Comment: It's $(10^6-1)/7$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More generally, this happens for the fraction $1/n$ exactly when $10$ is a primitive root mod $n$.

Those $n$ are the ones in [A167797](https://oeis.org/A167797):
$$
7, 17, 19, 23, 29, 47, 49, 59, 61, 97, 109, 113, 131, 149, 167, 179, 181, 193, \dots
$$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Answer (score 3):

Because
$\dfrac1{7}
=.142857142857...
$
and all
(and there is a lot)
that follows from that.

Comment: I don't think just mentioning this is helpful at all. The OP might have observed this besides you haven't mentioned how to further draw conclusions from this.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted.