# Why multiplication of 142857 with 2,3,4,5,6 gives the same digits shifted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I was reading about a not so practical way to determine the divisibility of a number by $7$.
At some point the following number is mentioned: $142857$ (which is the result of $\frac{999999}{7}$) and apparently this number as I have verified if multiplied by $2,3,4,5, 6$ it gives the same digits in different order e.g. $142857 \cdot 3 = 428571$

Why does this number have this property? I see that the numbers $2,3,4,5,6$ are all remainders if we divide $100, 10, 10000, 100000, 1000$ by $7$ respectively but I am not sure if there is any correlation with the property.
I'd like to understand the intuition behind this "trick"

Note: I have found a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333080/why-142857-when-multiplied-by-1-to-6-gives-the-same-digits) but I don't see any explanation on this

Comment: $$\frac{142857}{999999}=\frac17.$$ So $$\frac17=0.\overline{142857}.$$ Then use what you noticed.

Comment: More generally if $10$ is a generator modulo prime $p,$ you will get something like this. For example, $p=17$ gives the same result for $058235294117647,$ multiplying by $1,\dots,16.$  It is not just a different order, but a rotated order - some number of digits are cut off the end of $142857$ and placed in the front.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Comment: If you multiply $076923$ by $1,3,4,9,10,$ or $12,$ you get the same sets of digits, but other values do not work, because there is no solution to $10^k\equiv n\pmod {13}$ for $n=2,5,6,7,8,11.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why $142857$ when multiplied by $1$ to $6$ gives the same digits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333080/why-142857-when-multiplied-by-1-to-6-gives-the-same-digits)

Comment: @JeanMarie Same question yes , but the answers are so useless. I think we can get a better dupe target.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56989/cyclic-numbers-are-characterized-by-the-reciprocals-of-full-reptend-primes) is not a dupe target but talk about characterizing numbers such as $142857$.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon You are right.

Answer (score 7):

Well, one can note that $142857$ is a bit of a special number in that $\frac{1}{7}=0.\overline{142857}$, which means that, by long division, one obtains $\overline{142857}=142857142857142857...$ ad infinitum via the following algorithm:

Start with $1$.

$1=\color{green}{0}\times7+\color{red}{1}$ so $\frac{1}{7}=0.\text{something}$

To get this something, do:

$\color{red}{1}\times10 = 10 = \color{green}{1}\times7+\color{red}{3}$ (*)

$\color{red}{3}\times10 = 30 = \color{green}{4}\times7+\color{red}{2}$ (**)

$\color{red}{2}\times10 = 20 = \color{green}{2}\times7+\color{red}{6}$

$\color{red}{6}\times10 = 60 = \color{green}{8}\times7+\color{red}{4}$

$\color{red}{4}\times10 = 40 = \color{green}{5}\times7+\color{red}{5}$

$\color{red}{5}\times10 = 50 = \color{green}{7}\times7+\color{red}{1}$

Now, the remainder is $\color{red}{1}$, which is what we started with at equation (*), so we now have a loop which yields $\frac{1}{7}=0.\color{green}{\overline{142857}}$. In group-theoretic parlance, the fact that the loop closes after $6$ iterations means that $10$ has order $6$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^*$, i.e. $10^6\equiv1 \pmod{7}$ and $10^k\neq1\pmod7$ for $1 \leq k \leq 5$.

To understand why the digits are shifted when e.g. multiplying by $3$, just note that multiplying $\frac{1}{7}$ by $3$ means considering $\frac{3}{7}$ instead of $\frac{1}{7}$, and so the algorithm would start at equation (**) instead of (*), thus yielding $\color{green}{\overline{428571}}$ instead of $\color{green}{\overline{142857}}$.

So $\frac{3}{7}=\frac{3\times 142857}{999999} = \frac{428571}{999999} \Rightarrow 3\times142857 = 428571$

This explains the shift.

Comment: I don't follow the logic from the `To get this something, do` and on. What exactly does the remainder with 10,30,20,60,40,50 show and what is the idea behind doing this to determine the decimal part of the result of $\frac{1}{7}$?

Answer (score 3):

Good question!

Let's see if we can noodle it out.

$\frac {1,000,000 -1}7 = 142857$.

And $2\times \frac {1,000,000 -1}7 = $ what... now you point out that $100 = 7k + 2$ where $7 =14$ so $2 = 100-7k$

$2\times \frac {100,000 - 1}7= (100-7k)\frac {1,000,000-1}7 =$

$100\frac {1,000,000 - 1}7 - k(1,000,000 -1) =$

$14,285,700 - \overline{k000000} +k$.

Hmm.... that we *know* $k = 14$ seems to be a really nice coincidence.

$14,285,700 - 14,000,000 + 14 = 285714$ and of course the numbers are reversed.

If we can assume that if $10^{m_j} = (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)\times 7 + j$ for $j=2,3,4,5,6$ we'd be done.

After all we'd then have

$j \times 142,857=$

$(10^{m_j} -  (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)7)\frac {1,000,000-1}7 =$

$10^{m-j}142,857 - (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)7)1,000,000 + (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)7)= $

$[\overline{(\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)(\text{last }6-m_j\text{ digits of }142857)\underbrace{0...0}_{m-j}}]- [\overline{(\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)000000}]+(\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)=$

$\overline{(\text{last }6-m_j\text{ digits of }142857)(\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)}$

......

So how can we show that for all $m_j \le 6 $ that $10^{m_j} = (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857)\times 7 + j$

Well.....

we know that $\frac {1,000,000 -1}7 = 142,857$.

This means $\frac 17= \frac 1{1000000}\frac {1000000}7 = \frac 1{1000000}[142,857 + \frac 17]$.  That means $\frac 17 = 0.142857\overline{142,857}$.

Okay....

So if we multiply $\frac 17$ times $10^{m_j}$ we get $10^{m_j}\frac 17 = (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857) + (\text{some decimal part less than } 1)$.

So $10^{m_j} = 7 \times (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857) + 7\times(\text{some decimal part less than } 1)=$

$7 \times (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857) + (\text{some value less than } 7)$

but as $10^{m_j}$ is a natural number (not divisible by $7$) we have

$10^{m_j} =  7 \times (\text{first }m_j\text{ digits of }142857) +j$ for some $1 \le j \le 7$

And that's it.

This will actually be true of any $n$ so that $\gcd(n,10) = 1$

Take, say $\frac 1{17}= 0.\overline{0588235294117647}$

We should get $0588235294117647 \times 2..... 16$ should be the same digits shifted.  Try it.

Comment: $\frac{999,999}{7}=142857$. You used $1,000,000-1$ instead. But I don't understand how from $2\cdot 999,999 = 2\times \frac {1,000,000 -1}7  = 1,999,998$ we go to $285714$ via replacing $2$ with the formula for $100$.

Comment: If $100 = 7\times 14 + 2$ then $2 = 100 - 7\times 14$.  So $2\times \frac {999,999}7 = (100-7\times 14)\times \frac {999999}7 = (100 - 7\times 14)\times \frac {10^6 -1}7$  Now just expand $(100-7\times 14)\times \frac{10^6 - 1}7 = 100\times \frac {10^6-1}7 - 7\times 14\times \frac {10^6-1}7= 100\times \frac {10^6-1}7 +-14\times (10^6 -1) = 100\times \frac {10^6-1}7 - 14\times 10^6  + 14$.  ... Now $100\times {10^6-1}7$ will add two zeros to $142857$ to get $14285700$. And $-14\times 10^6=-14000000$ removes the leading $14$ to get $285700$ and $+14$ adds it back to the other side: $285714$.

Comment: $1999998 = 2\cdot 999,999 \ne 2\cdot \frac {999999}7=285714$.  Why did you do *anything* with $2\times 999999$ that was not part of the question and never part of my solution?

Comment: It $2 = 100 - 7\times 14$ (which it does) then $$2 \times ANYTHING = (100 -7\times 14)ANYTHING = 100\times ANYTHING - 7\times 14\times ANYTHING$$.  And if $$ANYTHING = 142857 = \frac {1000000 - 1}7$$ then $$2\times 142857 = 100\times 142857 - 7\times 14\times\frac {1000000 -1}7 = 100\times 142857 - 14\times 1000000 + 14$$.  $$=\color{green}{14}\color{red}{2857}\color{purple}{00} - \color{green}{14}\color{red}{0000}\color{purple}{00} + \color{purple}{14}= \color{red}{2857}\color{purple}{00}$$That's all.

Comment: Yes I got confused, sorry about that

Comment: What is a concrete example of the "$10^{m_j}$=(first  digits of 142857)". I am not sure I get this. Does it mean $10^1$ for the first 1 digit i.e. 1? Or $10^2$ for $m_j=14$?

Comment: $10^1 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$. And $10^1 = 7\times 1 + 3$.

$10^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  And $10^2 = 7\times 14+2$.

$10^3\equiv 6\pmod 7$.  And $10^3=7\times 142 + 6$.

$10^4 \equiv 4\pmod 7$  Ad $ 10^4=7\times 1428 + 4$.

$10^5 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.  And $10^5=7\times 14285 + 5$.

$10^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. And $10^6 =7\times 142857 + 1$.

Comment: This is *all* because $\frac 17 = 0.142857142857......$.  So $1 = 7\times 0.142857142857...$.  So $10 = 7\times 1.428571428571.... = 7\times 1 + something$.... And $10^2 = 7\times 14.285714285714..... = 7\times 14 + something$... And $10^3= 7\times 142.857142857142.... = 7\times 142 + something$.... and so on.