Pattern/trick to calculating 2/7, 3/7 etc.
One of my students pointed out an interesting trick for calculating multiples of $\dfrac{1}{7}$.
Suppose you have memorised $\dfrac{1}{7} = 0.\dot{1}4285\dot{7}$ where the dots mean everything between the dots is repeated.
The important part is the digits after the decimal point: $1,4,2,8,5,7$.
To calculate $\dfrac{2}{7}$, you start with the second lowest digit (which is $2$) and then keep the order of the numbers the same after the 2. So:
$\dfrac{2}{7} = 0.\dot{2}8571\dot{4}$
Similarly to calculate $\dfrac{3}{7}$ you cycle through the digits, starting at the third lowest (which is 4).
Why does this pattern occur?

Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256774/42969

One answer to this question is that this pattern occurs for fractions with denominator $p$, where $p$ is a prime such that $10$ is a primitive root modulo $p$

Next, you can try $1/17$ which is $0588235294117647$ repeating, and multiples of it show the same period with different starting points.  Then: in case $1/k$ has period $k-1$, it should also work the same way.

It can be proved that every rational ultimately ends with trailing $0$ or a cycle.
The reason is simple, there are only $7$ remains in the division by $7$, ie. $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ so sooner or later one will repeat and you will have a cycle.

$1$ divided by $7$ is $0$ remains $1$
we offset by $10$ and $10$ divided by $7$ is $1$ remains $3$
we offset by $10$ and $30$ divided by $7$ is $4$ remains $2$
we offset by $10$ and $20$ divided by $7$ is $2$ remains $6$
we offset by $10$ and $60$ divided by $7$ is $8$ remains $4$
we offset by $10$ and $40$ divided by $7$ is $5$ remains $5$
we offset by $10$ and $50$ divided by $7$ is $7$ remains $1$

and we go to the second line, because the remains $1$ is repeated.
Note that for $\frac 47$ for instance you will simply start the cycle from the line that spells "40 divided by 7", and cycle from there.
Of course this is identical with a larger denominator, just that the cycle may be longer.
By the way, the usual notation is $\frac 17=0.\overline{142857}\cdots\ $ with an overline to mean repeating digits.

I don't see how this answers OP's question.  Why does doubling, tripling, etc. simply shift the cycle downstream?  Doesn't happen with, say, 1/3.

This is because all possible remainders are exhausted in the division by $7$ so multiplying just makes you starts the cycle at a later index. In $\frac 13$ only remainder $1$ is activated.

@zwim Ok, but that is the pattern that the question is asking about, which you don't address in your answer
